# Error installing Drools plugin for Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, drools

Does anyone know how to fix this issue ?

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
>
> Software being installed: JBoss Runtime Drools Detector 6.3.0.Final (org.jboss.tools.runtime.drools.detector.feature.feature.group 6.3.0.Final)
> Missing requirement: JBoss Runtime Drools Detector 6.3.0.Final (org.jboss.tools.runtime.drools.detector.feature.feature.group 6.3.0.Final) requires 'org.jboss.tools.runtime.core.feature.feature.group 0.0.0' but it could not be found

Comment: What is your target eclipse version? I am asking because drools tools were discontinued a while ago and most likely don't work in latest eclipse rlelase.

Comment: How do you try to install it, from remote update site or from local archive?

Comment: I had the same issue when trying to install from the remote update site. As @dgolovin may be alluding to, a local install site would probably work.

Comment: @dgolovin  I am using the latest eclipse version. drools tools is still being released you  can download it form drools.org. I tried both local and remote install. It does not work in both.

Comment: @user1363516, sorry, I mixed it with different tools, so you cannot install "Drools and jBPM Tools" into Eclipse Mars.1, right?

Comment: @dgolovin from local  and remote

Answer (score 14):

You need to add http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/stable/luna/ update site into eclipse and select "Contact all update sites during install to find required software" before installing drools features.

Comment: http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/stable/mars for Eclipse Mars

Comment: http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/neon/stable/updates/ for Eclipse Neon

Answer (score 3):

@dgolovin and @user1363516 you can install "Drools and jBPM Tools" into Eclipse Mars 1. (i use eclipse Mars 1.) or if you got the error when installing follow the following steps below:

Step 1. Add http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/stable/luna/  as an update site. Help >> Install New Software

Step 2. Select only JBoss Application Development & JBoss Business Intelligence plugins they should total about 38 elements including drools core and drools runtime.

[image]

Step 3. Install those elements and restart eclipse.

Step 4. Install your Drools and jBPM Tools using the update site or downloaded archive. Most of the previosly uninstallable items should appear to be gone because they would have been installed when you used the jboss luna update site (Step 1).

Step 5. Complete installation, error should be gone and restart eclipse.