# Drools 6.4.0.Final Installation In Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, drools, eclipse-neon

I am trying to install drool 6.4.0.Final in eclipse Neon. I use the update site [url](http://download.jboss.org/drools/release/6.4.0.Final/org.drools.updatesite/)  and it works fine. But once eclipse starts calculating requirements etc. It proceeds to a page which shows that:

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could
>   not be found. Software being installed: JBoss Runtime Drools Detector
>   Developer Resources 6.4.0.Final
>   (org.jboss.tools.runtime.drools.detector.feature.source.feature.group
>   6.4.0.Final) Missing requirement: JBoss Runtime Drools Detector 6.4.0.Final (org.jboss.tools.runtime.drools.detector.feature.feature.group
>   6.4.0.Final) requires ‘org.jboss.tools.runtime.core.feature.feature.group 0.0.0’ but it
>   could not be found Cannot satisfy dependency: From: JBoss Runtime
>   Drools Detector Developer Resources 6.4.0.Final
>   (org.jboss.tools.runtime.drools.detector.feature.source.feature.group
>   6.4.0.Final) To: org.jboss.tools.runtime.drools.detector.feature.feature.group
>   [6.4.0.Final]

What’s going wrong here? Am I missing something?

FYI Eclipse GEF plugin installed successfully.

Comment: Any luck? A month later and this is still happening on the official update site. :-/

Comment: Another month and still facing this issue! Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Installing `JBoss Tools 4.4.0.Final` plugin before Drools plugin installation worked for me.

Or better see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/34204575/1562662. I haven't tried this, but seems to work.